# Screenshot Notification on Browser?

Tags: browser, screenshot, snapchat, webpage-screenshot

I wanted to know what would be the best route in mimicking the feature of snapchat of an application being aware of a user screenshotting the page?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

By the question I assume you are facing the problem of detecting a screenshot. We can monitor the clipboard and detect the application running in foreground. In case of any snipping tool, the screenshot goes to the clipboard and we can paste it directly.